# Change default tab for Media browser

Tags: media

Is it possible to change the default tab for Media browser (Media module) in Drupal 7?
Currently I have:
**Upload**, **Web**, **Library** and **My Files**.

I would like to open **Library** by default, instead of **Upload**.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

http://jimbir.ch/blog/changing-order-drupal-7-media-module-file-browser-tabs

I just tried and it works perfect:

> Blockquote
>
> Here is the original order of the file browser:
>
> In order to change the order and hook into this function, I created a simple custom module, mediamenu.  In this module, I will be able to hook into the media module using the hook Brandon showed me, and change the weight of the tabs, re-ordering them. The module has a folder named mediamenu, and inside two files, named mediamenu.info and mediamenu.module.  You can view and download these files from this github repo.
>   mediamenu.info
>
> The .info file contains information about the module, name, description, version, which version of Drupal, and where to group it on the modules page.
>
> ```
> name = Media Menu
> description = This module organizes the tabs on the Media browser.
> version = "7.x-1.0"
> core = "7.x"
> package = Media
> ```
>
> mediamenu.module
>
> In the .module file, we hook in and change the weights of the tabs, which will re-order them, the heaviest weight/lowest number first.
>
> The first two items here are provided by the Media module, and the Media Browser view (Machine name: media_default).  The two tabs are made by the two displays of the view,  media_browser_1 and
>   media_browser_my_files.  The media_internet tab is provided by the module of the same name.  Upload is provided by the media module.
>
> ```
> < ?php
> /**
>  * Change Order of Media Browser Tabs
>  *
>  * Implements hook_media_browser_plugin_info_alter().
>  */
> function mediamenu_media_browser_plugin_info_alter(&$info) {
>   $info['media_default--media_browser_1']['weight'] = '-10';
>   $info['media_default--media_browser_my_files']['weight'] = '-9';
>   $info['media_internet']['weight'] = '-8';
>   $info['upload']['weight'] = '-7';
> }
> ```
>
> You may have additional tabs provided by other modules. You can find their machine name but looking at the source markup of the page, and looking for the data-tabid of the tab.